# Optional parameters for a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to write a stored procedure with optional parameters.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvutJ.png) is what I get when I exec the stored procedure without parameters - it's ok. Also, when I do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDrTl.png) with the dept's name but when I used the last name as parameter throws [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvcSi.png) which is nothing

Any idea how to solve this? please!

Comment: **PLEASE** post your code, your executions, and your error messages **AS TEXT** in your question - not as screenshots off on some other site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third proc execution

```
exec consulta 'Gaitan'
```

is not being compared with last name. Its being passed as first parameter,since you did not specify the parameter names in procedure call.

Try adding parameter names to the procedure call. You should see what you are expecting.

Something like this:

```
exec consulta   @Apellido = 'Gaitan'
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass an optional parameter that is not the first parameter, you need to specifically mention the parameter name:

```
EXEC consulta @Apellido = 'Gaitan' -- Last name
EXEC consulta @nombre = 'Cirugia' -- Dept name
EXEC consulta 'Cirugia' -- Dept name (passed into @nombre)
```